# making a new array out of 2 arrays with the higher value inside

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy and I'm trying to compare between 2 arrays and get the higher value between them into a new array

```
arr1= array([1,2,3,4])
arr2= array([6,0,2,4])
newarr = array([6,2,3,4])
```

is there any way to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [`np.maximum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr2 = np.array([6, 0, 2, 4])
newarr = np.maximum(arr1, arr2)
print(newarr)
>>> [6 2 3 4]
```